# if/else extracting part of a UK postcode

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to extract the first part of a UK postcode using an if/else from the full postcode in javascript

Basically, if the postcode is in the format;

`AB99 9CD` it needs to return `AB`

`A9 9BC` it needs to return `A`

`A99 9BC` it needs to return `A`

`AB9C 9DE` it needs to return `AB`.

I thought about trying

```
if (fieldname == LETTER1 LETTER2 NUM NUM NUM LETTER3 LETTER 4) 
    return LETTER 1 LETTER 2;
```

and so on, then using the else as the error message, so that it's recognising the format & returning the first one or two letters but haven't got a clue what code to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikipeda entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation) on UK postcodes, the following Regex can be used to validate a UK postcode:

`^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$`

Using this, along with a capture group, will give you the "Area" part of the outer group in a UK postcode:

```js
("EC1A 1BB").match(/^([A-Z]{1,2})[0-9][A-Z0-9]? ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/)[1]
// Gives "EC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it:

```js
var str1 = 'AB99 9CD';
var str2 = 'A9 9BC';
var str3 = 'A99 9BC';
var str4 = 'AB9C 9DE';

var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z]+)/;

console.log('Letters 1:', str1.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Letters 2:', str2.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Letters 3:', str3.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Letters 4:', str4.match(pattern)[0]);
```

---

`^` mean: At the beginning.

`()` mean: A group.

`[a-zA-Z]` mean: Accepting alphabet characters.

`+` in this case, it mean: everything inside `[]` can be accepted one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting your address using the function split("your criteria"). Then, check for the first character. If it is a non-number with the function `isNaN()`

```js
function Verify(address) {
  var arrAdd = address.split(" ")
  
  if (isNaN(arrAdd[0][0])) {
    if (isNaN(arrAdd[0][1]))
      return arrAdd[0]
    else
      return arrAdd[0][0]
  }
}

console.log(Verify("A9 BBX"))
```